# Using Qwik vs NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, qwik

I am new to React and I would like to also learn NextJS. I've also discovered Qwik and I would like to know whether Qwik is an alternative to NextJS. Can I use Qwick and NextJS in the same project? Does Qwik City perform the same features of NextJS?
Thanks.

Comment: I do not know Qwik. However, as a simple indicator you could compare the weekly downloads of both: [Qwik (~2,000)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@builder.io/qwik) and [next (~2,000,000)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next). Anyway - this question is also off-topic on SO. Edit: _Can I use Qwick and NextJS in the same project?_ - I wouldn't recommend to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qwik is it's own Javascript framework like React, Vue, or Svelte—which are also JS frameworks (except React doesn't consider itself a full "framework", just a JS "library").

Quik City is a Quik framework like:

- NextJS is a React framework,
- SvelteKit a Svelte framework,
- and Nuxt is a Vue framework

Quik is different than other JS frameworks in that it aims to solve the problem of "hydration" by using a technique called resumability which allows it to be instantly interactive... amongst other things you can read about in it's documentation.

In short, no. It's not something you would use with NextJS. It is not React. It is Qwik.

...and for the most part Qwik City *does* perform the same features of NextJS.